# Adding pool heater to bonding of pump, salt generator, and timer

Tags: electrical, pool, grounding-and-bonding

I just recently  installed a heater and on the bonding lug my installer ran a green wire back inside the heater to the metal.

I could have sworn that they were supposed to run a wire from the bonding lug to join the other wire that is hooked to my pump, generator, and timer/thermostat. There is an existing bare copper wire ran from the ground through pump, to Salt generator, and back through my timer/thermostat.

Can someone look at these photos and tell me how this is usually done to give me an idea?

I know for a fact when building the pool there was copper wire ran all the way arond the pool, the hand rails, ladder, and light niche so that part should be fine.

Just wanted to make sure i am tying into this with the heater and being safe.

[image][image]

[image]

Comment: Where does this bonding wire *go*? I still am not sure what's on the other end of it...

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to hook up the bonding wire to that bonding lug. Right now it is hooked up to the earth ground, which is incorrect. Earth ground is to keep the pool equipment at earth potential, bonding is to keep all the pool equipment at the same potential. Run a bare #8 copper wire from the bonding lug on the pool heater to the bonding wire, and connect it using a split-bolt connector